# Как получить месяц из даты Excel в C#

Tags: c#

К примеру у меня в экселе в ячейке есть дата "26.01.2023", мне нужно перенести только месяц, то есть "01" и занести его в переменную. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вроде получилось, взял дату, обрезал её и перевёл в int

Comment: Да, получилось, а можно как-то перенести не таким способом?) 
'string monthExcel = sheet.Cells[7 + j, 1].Text;'
'monthExcel = monthExcel.Substring(2, 4).Replace(".", string.Empty);'

Comment: А что мешает использовать функцию "месяц"? 
   `=МЕСЯЦ(ДАТА(2021;2;5))`
Как пример работы с датами, взгляните [сюда](https://mister-office.ru/funktsii-excel/month-name.html#month-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `DateTime.ParseExact()`

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test {
  static void Main() {
    string data = "26.01.2023", format = "dd.mm.yyyy";
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(data,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month);
  }
}
```

Поскольку **дата в ячейке Excel - это число с двойной точностью (Double)**, то посмотрите ещё в сторону [DateTime.FromOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=net-7.0). Извлекать значение из ячейки Excel в этом случае нужно с помощью `.Value`, а не `.Text`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;

class Test {
  static void Main() {
    double data = 44952; // в Excel == 26.01.2023
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(data).Month);
  }
}
```

Результат:

```
1
```